# Create a new file out of calculating an existing one

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

Now I want to group by words and see how many times they show under one ORG('DMS') and how many times it shows in other ORG ('NONDMS') files. It should looks like this:

```
WORD   DMS(count) NOTDMS(count)
health   118          32
```

Here is the code I have. I could run the piece after SELECT, but could not write it into a new file.

```
CREATE Table  DMSCOUNT(WORD varchar(200), DMSTotal int, NOTDMSTotal int)

INSERT INTO DMSCOUNT
SELECT Word,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORG='DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORG != 'DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM temp
GROUP BY Word;
```

Error message: `Error at Command Line:3 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:

*Action:`.

Can anyone help me figure out what is the problems? FYI, this is the old post I shared the tables. Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: is this a script file you are executing? show us, how you are running the script file in command line? exactly where it's failing?

Comment: What does that mean? I opened a new sql window to run it. Updated my screenshot in my post. Thanks.

Comment: didn't get? the error is in `select query`? if so, are you sure table `temp` does exists?

Comment: The after `SELECT` part ran fine. Please check back my post. Updated my screenshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a semicolon `;` after your `create table` statement like below

```
CREATE Table  DMSCOUNT(WORD varchar(200), DMSTotal int, NOTDMSTotal int); <-- Here

INSERT INTO DMSCOUNT
SELECT Word,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORG='DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORG != 'DMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM temp
GROUP BY Word;
```

Comment: @Q-ximi,Yes, sometime it causes this wired problem. Don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped.